# Returning 404 error after using RewriteRule on localhost

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, 404, localhost

I would like to use `localhost/projects/project1/page/x` instead of  `localhost/projects/project1/index.php?page=x`. But after I had redirected the URL in .htaccess using RewriteRule, it returned my 404 error page.

Here is my code:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /projects/project1/pagenotfound.php

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^projects/project1/page/([0-9]*)$ /projects/project1/index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

---

### SOLUTION

```
ErrorDocument 404 /projects/project1/pagenotfound.php

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]*)$ /projects/project1/index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Temporarily add an `R=302` flag on the `RewriteRule` (it will now _externally redirect_, rather than _internally rewrite_, and make it easier to debug) - do you see the redirect? Do you still get the 404?

Comment: What happens when you get rid of QSA in your flags? After all, the friendly url has no query string attached to it.

Comment: Still not working. I tried added R=302 flag and still get the 404. Also tried it without QSA, still get 404.

Comment: And when you add the `R=302` what URL are you redirected to? ...What URL triggers the 404? `/projects/project1/index.php?page=0`?

Comment: In the browser the URL is: `localhost/projects/project1/page/1`, but what I can see is the `pagenotfound.php` (my own 404 error page).

Comment: If you are seeing `localhost/projects/project1/page/1` in the browsers address bar, after adding the `R=302` flag then the redirect/rewrite is not happening. Is mod_rewrite enabled? Is `AllowOverride` set appropriately in your server config? Where is your .htaccess file located?

Comment: Yes, I have checked that so many times, and mod_rewrite is enabled. Just like AllowOverride.

`LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`
and
`# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    AllowOverride All`
This is what annoyes me, that I set everything correctly and it doesn't work.

Comment: My .htaccess is in the same directory as the index.php, so: `localhost/projects/project1/.htaccess`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My .htaccess is in the same directory as the index.php, so: `localhost/projects/project1/.htaccess`

That's the problem, or rather your `RewriteRule` pattern is the problem, depending on how you look at it.

In .htaccess (per-directory) files, the per-directory prefix is first removed from the URL before matching against the pattern. So, if your .htaccess file is at `/projects/project1/.htaccess`, then your `RewriteRule` pattern needs to exclude `/projects/project1/` from the start (for the same reason you remove the `/` prefix from the pattern when in the document root). In other words...

```
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]*)$ /projects/project1/index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Or, move your .htaccess file to the document root.

Comment: @MártonJuhász If an answer "works" it is both polite and helpful to vote the answer up, as well as accepting it.

Comment: @FredGandt Thanks, much appreciated. However, a user requires 15+ rep in order to "vote up", even on answers to their own questions unfortunately.

Comment: My derp; completely forgot. I'll vote the question up too, and hope they get back to you ;-)